# Dynamically moving down an element in the header in JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

In JQuery Mobile I am creating an header with a Back button aligned in the left side and a title aligned centre. Ideally these two elements should be aligned in the same line, but when for space reason the two elements can't be accommodated (especially in portray mode) in the same row, the title should be moved a bit down below the Back button. What CSS attribute should be used?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="back-header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" position="absolute" data-theme="a">

    <a href="index.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" class="back-button">Back</a>

    <p class="menu-label" align="center">
            <img src="images/biglogoreduced.png" class="menu-label-image" height="20" width="20">
        Data Monitor
    </p>


</div>
```

Comment: please post your code for it to be clearer.

Comment: maybe use position relative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made you a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/TRZjY/

Resize a "Result window" to see a difference.

```
@media all and (max-width: 300px) {
    h3.ui-title {
        margin: 40px 5% 0.8em !important;
        white-space: normal !important;
    }
}
```

Customize **max-width: 300px** to your needs, depending on your title. Also change 
**margin: 40px 5% 0.8em !important;**. You should change only 40px, because I am using h3 tag as a title container.